# Export video with custom CMTimeRange issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, range, avasset, cmtime

I guess i'm missing something. I have a slider which changes the asset duration, and the start time as well.
If i'm exporting the video with the full duration, as

```
 let timeRange = originalVideoTrack.timeRange
        do {
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: originalVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {

        }
```

Everything works. 
But if i try to insert my custom duration, as

```
 let startTime = CMTimeMake(Int64(CMTimeGetSeconds(videoRangeSlider.timeRange.start) * 1000)   , 1000)
        let dura = CMTimeGetSeconds(videoRangeSlider.timeRange.end) - CMTimeGetSeconds(videoRangeSlider.timeRange.start)
let duration = CMTimeMake( Int64(dura * 1000)  , 1000)
t timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime,duration)
 originalVideoTrack.timeRange
        do {
                try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: originalVideoTrack, atTime: timeRange.start)

        } catch {
            print("problem")
        }
```

**I've changed `atTime` to kCGTimeZero as well, won't work**

Any suggestions?

**Update**

Example timeRange

```
CMTimeRange(start: __C.CMTime(value: 2216, timescale: 1000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), duration: __C.CMTime(value: 2880, timescale: 1000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0))
```

Comment: Is the `videoRangeSlider.timeRange.start` a `CMTime` type?

Comment: @J.Wang Hey Wang, Yes it does.

Comment: Then you can use it directly in the `atTime` right? And also you can use `CMTimeSubtract` to get the duration of two `CMTime`.

Comment: @J.Wang I did, Didn't work as well.  videoRangeSlider.timeRange is the asset current TimeRange, but still, it dosent work..

Comment: @J.Wang Ive edited my question, added the custom CMTimeRange example

Comment: Do a `catch let e` and `print(e)` to see the error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105556/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-j-wang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved. Enjoy**

Insert the full time range as

```
 let timeRange = originalVideoTrack.timeRange
        do {
            try videoTrack.insertTimeRange(timeRange, ofTrack: originalVideoTrack, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        } catch {

        }
```

And than, for your `customRange`, do as follow

```
    exportSession?.timeRange = customRange
```